# Heroku application not syncing up with Mongo atlas database and now keeps crashing

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I have an application I built that was deploying find on the front end on heroku but now keep crashing after I have tried to fix an issue with the application not connecting with my mongo atlas database. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but the heroku logs say:

```
"2022-12-05T10:19:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-12-05T10:19:24.577606+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-12-05T10:19:26.144610+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-12-05T10:19:26.144634+00:00 app[web.1]: > littledb@1.0.0 start
2022-12-05T10:19:26.144634+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2022-12-05T10:19:26.144635+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-12-05T10:19:26.369713+00:00 app[web.1]: Running on port: 36914
2022-12-05T10:19:26.725509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-12-05T10:19:56.365761+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected successfully to db server
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367567+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:698
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367568+00:00 app[web.1]:           throw error;
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367569+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367569+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367571+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'db')
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367571+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/dal.js:10:17
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367572+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:695:9
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367572+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:285:23
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367573+00:00 app[web.1]:     at connectCallback (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:367:5)
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367574+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:554:14
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367576+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.connectHandler [as callback] (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:286:11)
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367576+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:443:25)
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367577+00:00 app[web.1]:     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367577+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367581+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-12-05T10:19:56.367581+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v18.12.1
2022-12-05T10:19:56.506120+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-12-05T10:19:56.549771+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed"
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "littledb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "lowdb sample for 1.125",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "abel@mit.edu",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "http-server": "^14.1.1",
    "lowdb": "^1.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.7.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mongodb": "^4.0.7"
  }
}
```

dal.js

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url         = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
let db            = null;
 
// connect to mongo
MongoClient.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true}, function(err, client) {
    console.log("Connected successfully to db server");

    // connect to myproject database
    db = client.db('baddestbank');
});

// create user account
function create(name, email, password){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const collection = db.collection('users');
        const doc = {name, email, password, balance: 0};
        collection.insertOne(doc, {w:1}, function(err, result) {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(doc);
        });    
    })
}

// find user account
function find(email){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const customers = db
            .collection('users')
            .find({email: email})
            .toArray(function(err, docs) {
                err ? reject(err) : resolve(docs);
        });    
    })
}

// find user account
function findOne(email){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const customers = db
            .collection('users')
            .findOne({email: email})
            .then((doc) => resolve(doc))
            .catch((err) => reject(err));    
    })
}

// update - deposit/withdraw amount
function update(email, amount){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const customers = db
            .collection('users')            
            .findOneAndUpdate(
                {email: email},
                { $inc: { balance: amount}},
                { returnOriginal: false },
                function (err, documents) {
                    err ? reject(err) : resolve(documents);
                }
            );            


    });    
}

// all users
function all(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const customers = db
            .collection('users')
            .find({})
            .toArray(function(err, docs) {
                err ? reject(err) : resolve(docs);
        });    
    })
}


module.exports = {create, findOne, find, update, all};
```

Also I am not sure if its relevant but on my dal.js on VS code if I mouse over where it says require("mongodb").client it says: "

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'mongodb'. '/Users/brit/Documents/MIT/thebaddestbank/node_modules/mongodb/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/mongodb` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'mongodb';`ts(7016)
```

"

I did what it says but in the terminal it says you no longer have to specify @types/mongodb so idk what the issue is.

my config vars on heroku is correct. I have pasted it from mongo atlas and replaced  with my password and have made the key MONGODB_URI so I am completely lost on what I am doing wrong or why the backend is not syncing my data when I input it on the app. On atlas I have also made sure to allow all IP addresses.

It is working perfectly locally but not sure what the deal is one deployment.
This project is due in 3 days for my very expensive MIT course and if I do not get it up and running I will fail so any advice is appreciated.

[Github repository](https://github.com/britniej/thebaddestbank)

I was expecting the app to load as it does locally and connect successfully to the mongo atlas database but now the app is crashing and before it started crashing it was not pushing data to my database and would not let users authenticate their accounts due to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It can often be difficult to connect to deployed databases when you have hardcoded references. Can I make some suggestions:

1 - Use environment variables or configuration specific for local development and production

- Install dotenv `npm i dotenv`
- Create an `.env` file in the root of your project
- Add a line like this to the `.env` files - `DB_URI='mongodb://localhost:27017'`
- Somewhere at the beginning of `index.js` or `dal.js` call `require('dotenv').config()`
- No longer hardcoded the `url` in `dal.js`, instead, use `const url = process.env.DB_URI`
- Go into your heroku config and set the `DB_URI` value to whatever it needs to be for your production deployment. [See heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Why? A change in DB url or any other configuration is a pain to change in code, you shouldn't. Instead, you can add variables to your environment (eg, in heroku and your local machine) and there will be zero code changes required. Much less brittle.

2 - Only start your web server (or run any important tasks) ONCE you've connected to your database

Create a function in `dal.js` that connects to your database, and make sure you wait until it is connected before allowing it to return

```
function connectToDB () {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const url = process.env.DB_URI
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, client) {
      if (err) console.error(err)
      console.log('Connected successfully to db server')
      db = client.db('myproject')
      resolve()
    })
  })
}
```

Call this before you start your web server, eg, in the bottom of `index.js`, do something like this:

```
const init = async () => {
  await dal.connectToDB()
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
  app.listen(port)
  console.log('Running on port: ' + port)
}
init()
```

Why? It's much better to wait for an established connection before giving the false illusion that you're ready to start processing. There are some exceptions, but it is a healthy basic premise.